# Run DotCover dotnet test with Cake

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, cakebuild, dotcover

Currently I run DotCover for each text project in my solution.
I want to change this to only run DotCover once for the whole solution.

I found this command which works:

```
C:\_git\MyApp\build\tools\JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.2021.1.3\tools\dotCover.exe dotnet --output=C:\Temp\report.xml --reporttype=xml -- test "C:\_git\MyApp\MyApp.sln"
```

My build scripts are written in Cake and I like to execute this command from within Cake.
However, online I can only find ways to run DotCover for a single test project like this:

```
var dotCoverCoverSettings = new DotCoverCoverSettings();
dotCoverCoverSettings.WithAttributeFilter( "System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute" );

DotCoverCover( tool => {
  tool.DotNetCoreTest(
    "test. dll",
    new DotNetCoreTestSettings() {                    
      Configuration = configuration
    }
  );
  },
  "out.xml",
  dotCoverCoverSettings
);
```

Is there a method in Cake for running the first DotCover command using dotnet test for a solution file?

I know about `StartProcess` but I would prefer a specific method to run DotCover.
If `StartProcess` is the only option, is there a built in way to resolve the path to the dotCover exe (NuGet package `#tool nuget:?package=JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools`) downloaded by cake?

```
StartProcess(
@"C:\_git\MyApp\build\tools\JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.2021.1.3\tools\dotCover.exe",
new ProcessSettings {
    Arguments = new ProcessArgumentBuilder()
        .Append( "dotnet" )
        .Append( @"--output=C:\Temp\report.dotCover.dcvr" )
        .Append( "--reporttype=XML" )
        .Append( @"-- test ""C:\_git\MyApp\MyApp.sln""" )
    }
);
```

**Edit:**

As @Nils has suggested; Passing the solution file as argument to DotNetCoreTest works. But DotCover "randomly" freezes when invoked using this code:

```
DotCoverCover( tool => {
    tool.DotNetCoreTest(
      Paths.SolutionFilePath.ToString(),
      new DotNetCoreTestSettings() {                    
        Configuration = configuration,
        NoBuild = true,
        NoRestore = true
      }
    );
    },
    dotCoverOutputFileName,
    dotCoverCoverSettings
);
```

It prints the results for some of the test projects and then nothing...

```
Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:    51, Skipped:     0, Total:    51, Duration: 220 ms - Proj1.Test.dll (net5.0)
Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:    26, Skipped:     0, Total:    26, Duration: 247 ms - Proj2.Test.dll (net5.0)
Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:    28, Skipped:     0, Total:    28, Duration: 249 ms - Proj3.Test.dll (net5.0)
Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:    31, Skipped:     0, Total:    31, Duration: 123 ms - Proj4.Test.dll (net5.0)
Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:   124, Skipped:     0, Total:   124, Duration: 3 s - Proj5.Test.dll (net5.0)
Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:   660, Skipped:     0, Total:   660, Duration: 5 s - Proj6.Test.dll (net5.0)
```

The problem could be that Cake uses other arguments to run DotCover:

`C:/_git/MyApp/build/tools/JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.2021.1.3/tools/dotCover.exe Cover /TargetExecutable="C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe" /TargetArguments="test \"../MyApp.sln\" --configuration Release --no-build --no-restore" /Output="C:/Temp/MyApp.sln.dotCover.dcvr"`

Arguments "reccomended" by JetBrains (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-9681)

`C:\_git\MyApp\build\tools\JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.2021.1.3\tools\dotCover.exe dotnet --output=C:\Temp\report.html --reporttype=html -- test "C:\_git\MyApp\MyApp.sln"`

I run the last command in a loop to see if i could reproduce the "freeze-issue" but sofare it works.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the full path of the solution as first argument of `DotNetCoreTest`? (I.e. Giving the solution instead of a project.)

In the end, the the [`DotNetCoreTester`](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/a1893a2bba26f49e089d66beeb78421cedf6126d/src/Cake.Common/Tools/DotNetCore/Test/DotNetCoreTester.cs#L60) simply passes that as first argument to `dotnet test`. So.. according to [dotnet-test docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) that can be `[<PROJECT> | <SOLUTION> | <DIRECTORY> | <DLL>]`.

Maybe the docs on the cake [`DotNetCoreAliases`](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreAliases/) are simply not quite as accurate.

EDIT:

While [`DotNetCoreTester`](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/a1893a2bba26f49e089d66beeb78421cedf6126d/src/Cake.Common/Tools/DotNetCore/Test/DotNetCoreTester.cs#L60) works fine with solutions as arguments and thus is able to run multiple test projects at once, [dotCover for .NET Framework](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html#basic) tests (which is what is called in `DotCoverCover`) is not able to process this.

The solution given in the [linked youtrack-issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DCVR-9681) is to use `dotCover.exe dotnet`, the [dotCover syntax for .NET Core](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html#basic-scenario-for-net-core) which is currently not implemented in Cake.

So it seems you are presented with three options:

- Use the `StartProcess` syntax you mentioned above
- Use the dotCover approach for multiple projects, [as laid out in the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html#covering-multiple-test-projects): Search for all test projects in your solution, cover each one on it's own and finally run [`DotCoverMerge`](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotCover/DotCoverAliases/) to merge the reports.
- Create an [issue in the Cake project](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues) that describes the missing functionality. (And ideally start working on a PR to implement it.)

Comment: I tried this. It works some times but, some runs just freeze. DotCover Prints the results of a test project and then nothing. When looking at the diagnostic output of cake it uses a different command to run dotcover `C:/_git/MyApp/build/tools/JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools.2021.1.3/tools/dotCover.exe Cover /TargetExecutable="C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe" /TargetArguments="test \"../MyApp.sln\" --configuration Release --no-build --no-restore" /Output="C:/Temp/MyApp.sln.dotCover.dcvr" `

Comment: So the youtrack issue you linked specifically talks about `dotCover.exe dotnet` and the commandline syntax mentioned there is not "best practice" but simply the syntax for `dotCover.exe dotnet` while the `DotCoverCover` method in Cake utilizes the `dotCover.exe cover` command. It seems the wrappers in Cake currently are missing an alias `dotCover.exe cover`. I modified my answer accordingly.